# How to include specific js modules instead of entire bundle.min.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use https://stackoverflow.design/product/guidelines/using-stacks/ in my project.  The problem is that I want to debug the code in a specific javascript file but since the entire bundle is incldued, the debugger opens `min.js` file instead of the specific module. What should I do to not rely on the `min.js` but on all the files separately?

**EDIT**
Here is how I'm running editor with `min` files. What should I change to run it without referencing `min` files?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Markdown Editor</title>
        <!--include Stacks -->
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="./node_modules/@stackoverflow/stacks/dist/css/stacks.css"
        />
        <!-- include the bundled styles -->
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="./node_modules/@stackoverflow/stacks-editor/dist/styles.css"
        />

        <!-- highlight.js is not included in the bundle, so include it as well if you want it -->
        <script src="//unpkg.com/@highlightjs/cdn-assets@latest/highlight.min.js"></script>
        <!--include Stacks -->
        <script src="./node_modules/@stackoverflow/stacks/dist/js/stacks.min.js"></script>
        <!-- include the bundle -->
        <script src="./node_modules/@stackoverflow/stacks-editor/dist/app.bundle.js"></script>

        <script
            scr="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full"
        ></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div style="margin: 20px; width: 800px">
            <div id="editor-container"></div>
            <!-- initialize the editor -->
            <script>
                new window.stacksEditor.StacksEditor(
                    document.querySelector("#editor-container"),
                    "*Your* **markdown** here",
                    {}
                );
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: During development, include your module directly instead of bundling it if possible. Or make sure you packager also outputs source maps that wllow your code to be remapped back to the original files.

Comment: Don't reference the min.js file, instead install the npm package. To include Stacks in other projects, you can install Stacks via NPM: npm install --save @stackoverflow/stackshttps://stackoverflow.design/product/guidelines/using-stacks/#installing

Comment: I edited my post. I installed stacks via npm but how can I rewrite my code to not reference `min` files? I tried `<script src="./node_modules/@stackoverflow/stacks-editor/dist/stacks-editor/editor.js"></script>`  but it doesnt work - I've got `Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

Comment: Just a note — use `src` instead of `scr` when referencing MathJax.